# Java splitting string ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, indexing, split, bounds

I'm getting java.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds... I don't know why.

```
    private final static String TEST_STRING = "My awesome string !^:_TEEEEEEEEEEEEEST";

    public void createPartControl(Composite parent){
        String[] temp = TEST_STRING.split("^:_");
        System.out.println(temp[0] + " ---> " + temp[1]);
    }
```

EDIT:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1   at
>   com.chriss.cipher.View.createPartControl(View.java:17)    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:386)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:240)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:315)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:534)    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695104/java-split-on-caret-not-working-is-this-a-special-character

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`split` accepts a regular expression, where `^` has special meaning: The beginning of the character sequence. This means that you aren't actually splitting the string as you expect. Escape the `^` sign with `\`:

```
TEST_STRING.split("\\^:_");
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.split(regex)` accepts **regex** as parameter, you need to escape `^` with backslash, as `^` in regex world is a special character(meta charcter)

```
    String[] temp = TEST_STRING.split("\\^:_");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] temp = TEST_STRING.split("\\^:_");
```

Answer (score 0):

private final static String TEST_STRING = "My awesome string !^:_TEEEEEEEEEEEEEST";

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent){
    String[] temp = TEST_STRING.split("\\^:_");
    System.out.println(temp[0] + " ---> " + temp[1]);
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Pattern.quote(String)` to quote all potentially regex special codes with `\`.

```
String[] deviceParts = deviceID.split(Pattern.quote("."));
```

or - in your case -

```
String[] temp = TEST_STRING.split(Pattern.quote("^:_"));
```