# String pattern on ^^ [Java]

Tags: java, regex

This is my code and it works with `-` but not with `^`, I know the reason, but I don't know the solution.

This code works and gives me *"here"*:

```
String patternString = "(.*)--(.*)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher m = r.matcher("here--asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd");
```

This code **doesn't** give me *"here"*:

```
String patternString = "(.*)^^(.*)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher m = r.matcher("here^^asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd");
```

Comment: The "^" is an anchor character, and you have to escape it.

Comment: `^` is a regex expression and though has to be escaped with `\\^`

Comment: @KevinEsche if I put \\  I get the `no way` not `here`

Comment: Listen to Kevin (both of them), they speak the truth. ;-)

Comment: String patternString = "(.*)\\^\\^(.*)"; this is my patter that generates no way instead of here

Comment: [Java split on ^ (caret?) not working, is this a special character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695104/java-split-on-caret-not-working-is-this-a-special-character)

Comment: @Andreas I won't listen to them, I will see their comments and reply ;)

Comment: Stupid Java doesn't know you aren't looking for a beginning when you use this special character at any other place than the start of a pattern. At least PHP knows this and treats it as a normal character when you use it anywhere but at the start of a pattern. EDIT: I'm wrong, of course.

Comment: @klaar: [Are you sure?](https://regex101.com/r/yU5sN8/1) You seem to confuse that with the caret use in character classes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I'm sorry I was mistaken, what I said only happens when you use it inside a character class, where it will be used as a negative-class marker when at the start of a class, or a regular character when not. Outside of the character class, it's always a special character.

Comment: @klaar Same for Java. In a character class `^` only has meaning as first character, and `-` only has meaning as middle character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `^` by `\\^`, that's a special symbol that represents the beginning of a line as [MULTILINE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) modifier is not enabled. Such symbols (`\.[]{}()*+-?^$|`) have to be escaped with `\\` before them.

Comment: Actually, here `^` is  a beginning of the string as MUTILINE modifier is not defined.

Comment: this generates `no way` instead of `here`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape both of the `^` characters (or group them), they are special characters in a regular expression. When I change your second example like,

```
String patternString = "(.*)\\^\\^(.*)";
```

or like

```
String patternString = "(.*)\\^{2}(.*)";
```

I get your (expected) `here`.